# Perfect Amazon Link Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build the perfect amazon link regex for use in javascript.  This is what I have so far:

```
var reg = /https?:\/\/(www|smile)\.amazon\.com\/(?:(?:[\w-]+\/)?(?:dp|gp\/product)\/(\w{10})\/)?/;
```

I want this to match all of the following urls in their entirety:

```
http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0005ZH4QI/?tag=menasheh02-20&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER
http://www.amazon.com/gp/family/signup/info/?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&linkCode=ur2&ref_type=generic&refcust=5FNWKEJKP63HFBSY6JGLXL4XIQ&tag=menasheh02-20&linkId=HR76ZTGJKWO5ED2N
http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fsubscribe-and-save%2Fmanager%2Fviewsubscriptions%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dya%255FT15%255F33&tag=menasheh02-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=390957
http://www.amazon.com/gp/student/signup/info?ie=UTF8&refcust=7EATHY4IXOFTTEMLIHVC3YL6DI&ref_type=generic
http://www.amazon.com/gp/video/primesignup?tag=menasheh02-20
https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0005ZH4QI/?tag=menasheh02-20&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER
https://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=s9_acss_gb_cg_HTLLPCGB_3d1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A165793011%2Cn%3A!2334111011%2Cn%3A!2334173011%2Cn%3A15539865011%2Cp_n_age_range%3A165936011%2Cp_72%3A1248963011&bbn=15539865011&ie=UTF8&qid=1476851901&rnid=1248961011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=events-center-c-4&pf_rd_r=8MKN8SY6C5ZP4NC1C0RB&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_p=e4acec8d-70de-466a-be44-05291b40a5d4&pf_rd_i=HTL_desktop
https://www.amazon.com/b/ref=s9_acss_gb_cg_HTLLPCGB_11a1?node=13521759011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=events-center-c-4&pf_rd_r=8MKN8SY6C5ZP4NC1C0RB&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_p=e4acec8d-70de-466a-be44-05291b40a5d4&pf_rd_i=HTL_desktop
https://www.amazon.com/Doctor-Vortex-Manipulator-Sonic-Screwdriver/dp/B001PR1ZII/ref=gbph_tit_e-7_fb02_fc8a0d34?smid=AOUT97QIB451U&pf_rd_p=8e268714-ad3d-444b-b0df-d51d8825fb02&pf_rd_s=events-center-c-7&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=HTL_desktop&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=8MKN8SY6C5ZP4NC1C0RB
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0005ZH4QI/?tag=menasheh02-20&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER
https://www.amazon.com/gp/coupon/skippy-baking-sale/A2UI00T2I5JAV3?ie=UTF8&heroAsin=B0005ZH4QI&source=grid_db_13285418011&pf_rd_p=782d30de-8b22-4b3d-9009-0f7a0cb995d3&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-3&pf_rd_t=Landing&pf_rd_i=13285418011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=PPNJHXVZRMM4XP9KXGGG
https://www.amazon.com/Monster-High-School-Playset/dp/B006O6F932/ref=gbph_tit_e-7_fb02_85d3d028?smid=A3CXJV2JYTL237&pf_rd_p=8e268714-ad3d-444b-b0df-d51d8825fb02&pf_rd_s=events-center-c-7&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=HTL_desktop&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=8MKN8SY6C5ZP4NC1C0RB
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=s9_acss_gb_cg_HTLLPCGB_3d1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A165793011%2Cn%3A!2334111011%2Cn%3A!2334173011%2Cn%3A15539865011%2Cp_n_age_range%3A165936011%2Cp_72%3A1248963011&bbn=15539865011&ie=UTF8&qid=1476851901&rnid=1248961011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=events-center-c-4&pf_rd_r=8MKN8SY6C5ZP4NC1C0RB&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_p=e4acec8d-70de-466a-be44-05291b40a5d4&pf_rd_i=HTL_desktop
```

And none of these:

```
https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=bad+regex&oq=bad+regex&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30k1l9.724.2089.0.2265.10.9.0.0.0.0.269.1091.0j4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..4.5.821.0..0i20k1j0i131k1j0i10k1.k62wRudUpsw
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/B53C945A8D?randomstuff=34341&otherrandomstuff=2
```

Right now, it's not matching either of the bad ones - that part is relatively simple.  (It's also not matching the url with `gp/redirect.html?` in it.) The tricky part is getting the match to return each useful part of the url separately, especially considering the if/elses and #.

# Working #

`match[1]` should equal either "www" or "smile."

`match[2]` should equal the ASIN, or be blank if the url doesn't have `/dp/%ASIN%`, `%SEO-string%/dp/%ASIN%`, or `/gp/product/%ASIN%`

[# Not Working #](http://regexr.com/3elna)

`match[3]` should equal the rest of the url after the .com, or after the product if ASIN is set, but NOT including a # at the end

`match[4]` should equal from the start of match[3] to `tag=`, if that is present.

`match[5]` should equal the tag parameter, if it exists

`match[6]` should equal the rest of the url between the tag parameter (if it exists; otherwise blank) and the # (if it exists, otherwise to end)

`match[7]` should equal the # at the end and anything after it, or blank if there is not one

I'm just getting into the more complicated regexes, and getting stuck on things like not going all the way to the end of the line if there's a #, etc;.

Can anybody more experienced help? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `RegExp` constructor, use regex literal.

Comment: @Tushar for use with the match function?  How do you mean?

Comment: `var regex = /https?:\/\/(www|smile)\.amazon\.com\/(?:(?:[\w-]+\/)?(?:dp|gp\/product)\/(\w{10})\/)?([\w\/=-]+)?([\w\/?=-]+)?(\?.+)(#[\w]+)?/;` then _# Not Working In JS #_ problems will be solved. In `RegExp` constructor as string is passed the slashes need to be escaped.

Comment: For the record, using [the `URL` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to subdivide the URL and process components independently might be something to consider. Create an anchor tag with the URL (don't even need to put it in DOM) if you don't have one, then you can access `anchor.hostname`, `anchor.pathname`, `anchor.search`, etc., so you're not trying to do all the work in a single unreadable regex.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks, now it works as well in js as in regexr.  I probably lost some better regex to toying with that... oh well.  Anyway, question updated.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'll check that out, but I would much prefer a single unreadable regex.

Comment: It almost seems unnecessary to try and pack this into one regex (unless you're one of my friends over at [Codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)). I would recommend a divide and conquer strategy, even though it would be so much less cool :P

Comment: @MayorMonty are you suggesting a migration?

Comment: No, [Codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), is an Exchange based on making your code as short as possible. Oftentimes, in order to do that, you have to do some crazy stuff in order to do that, like making such a pervasive regex. It was more a joke than anything

Comment: @Menasheh what did you end up finding - did you come up with the perfect Amazon Link Regex? Or did you find something more reliable? I would love to hear the outcome of your investigation.

Answer (score 5):

Try this Regex which works with javascript:

```
https?:\/\/(?=(?:....)?amazon|smile)(www|smile)\S+com(((?:\/(?:dp|gp)\/([A-Z0-9]+))?\S*[?&]?(?:tag=))?\S*?)(?:#)?(\w*?-\w{2})?(\S*)(#?\S*)+
```

I made a little change:

> match[3] & match[4] = match[2] & match[3]
>
> match[2] = match[4].

Hope it helps.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sT2wj8/2

Comment: Why are google and sell involved - they're not supposed to be matched!  This is specifically for amazon urls

Comment: @Menasheh They are not. This symbol `?!` which is located before them means "do not match what is between parenthesis". Anyway, I updated the code, and removed them. Check out the matched groups in the demo.